# How does kNNdist the computing which distance formula uses it in the dbscan package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, dbscan

How does it gets to it's output? Does it uses euclidean distance? By row, or per columns I can't figure out.

```
library("dbscan")

i <- iris[1:10,-5]
i 
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
[2,]          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
[3,]          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
[4,]          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
[5,]          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
[6,]          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
[7,]          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
[8,]          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2
[9,]          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
[10,]         4.9         3.1           1.5        0.1

 x <- kNNdist(i,k = 5)
 x
              1         2         3         4         5
 [1,] 0.1414214 0.1732051 0.4690416 0.5099020 0.5196152
 [2,] 0.1732051 0.3000000 0.3316625 0.4242641 0.5099020
 [3,] 0.2449490 0.2645751 0.3000000 0.3162278 0.4123106
 [4,] 0.2449490 0.3000000 0.3162278 0.3316625 0.3316625
 [5,] 0.1414214 0.2236068 0.4582576 0.5099020 0.5291503
 [6,] 0.6164414 0.6164414 0.7000000 0.9949874 1.0099505
 [7,] 0.2645751 0.3316625 0.4242641 0.4582576 0.4795832
 [8,] 0.1732051 0.2236068 0.3316625 0.4123106 0.4242641
 [9,] 0.3000000 0.4358899 0.5099020 0.5477226 0.5567764
 [10,] 0.1732051 0.3162278 0.3162278 0.3316625 0.4690416
```

Comment: Look at the code. All CRAN packages are open source.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, these are the *Euclidean* distances to the kNN.